# In styled-component, the button onClick event didn't working what I expected

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

After updating 'React-Router-Dom' in version6, I've studied functional components and styled-component. I am sorry if I asking such a stupid question.

I tried to make a button and when I click the button(onClick event) it changes the background color. So I tried to give pass the color in props and changing it when onClick event happened. When I check the developer tool, the color part change(#f4f4f4 or #f22).
[image]

So, I tried to setting setState and setState like this

```
export default function MarketPrice() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#f4f4f4');
  const onClick = () => {
    color === '#f4f4f4' ? setColor('#fff') : setColor('#f4f4f4');
  };
  return (
    <MarketPriceWrapper>
      <TitleWrapper>
        <MarketPriceTitle>시세</MarketPriceTitle>
        <showAllSizes>
          <AllSize>모든 사이즈</AllSize>
          <FaRegArrowAltCircleDown />
        </showAllSizes>
      </TitleWrapper>
      <salesGraphWrapper>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
      </salesGraphWrapper>
      <ButtonsWrapper>
        <Button color={color} onClick={onClick}>
          체결 거래
        </Button>
        <Button color={color} onClick={onClick}>
          판매 입찰
        </Button>
        <Button color={color} onClick={onClick}>
          구매 입찰
        </Button>
      </ButtonsWrapper>
    </MarketPriceWrapper>
  );
}

const MarketPriceWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
`;

const TitleWrapper = styled.div`
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
`;
const MarketPriceTitle = styled.span`
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
`;
const AllSize = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  font-size: 18px;
`;

const ButtonsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  display: block;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 7px 0 9px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  background-color: ${props => (props.onClick ? '#f4f4f4' : '#222')};
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
`;
```

Here is a button that I want to change the background color when I clicked it
[image]

Furthermore, is it okay with using the same component name as the button? I wonder if I click one of the buttons it changes the all-button background color.

It would be really appreciate your help!

Comment: The problem is here: `background-color: ${props => (props.onClick ? '#f4f4f4' : '#222')};` should be `background-color: ${props => props.color};`. Please note, this will set all 3 buttons to the same color, not just the one clicked. If you'd like to change just the one clicked you will need to track the color with different state variables (or an `active` state variable)

Comment: @CalIrvine First of all, thank you for trying to help me out. I got your point. I should be get props.color! And when I click one of them, It changes all buttons background color what I expected...

Comment: exactly. If you wanted change just the `active` button color, you might want to add a prop `isActive` and keep track of which button is active. `<Button isActive={activeButton === button1} />` then in your styles `background-color: ${props => (props.isActive ? '#f4f4f4' : '#222')};`

Comment: @CalIrvine then If i want to use isActive, activeButton, and button1. Do I have to setState each of them?

Comment: no, `isActive` would be a prop on `Button`, and `button1` is just an example of how you can differentiate your three buttons. The implementation is up to you. `activeButton` would be your only state.